# Systems with a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ spontaneous symmetry breaking transition?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking, ising-model, critical-phenomena

I am studying spontaneous $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry breaking transition for some time now in quantum (transverse-field) and classical Ising systems. I would like to look beyond my little box in terms of realisations of this Ising universality in other physical systems.

Therefore I would like to start a discussion/collection on this platform of all kinds of physical systems displaying spontaneous $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry breaking transition.

My explicit question is:
**Which systems have a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ spontaneous symmetry breaking transition?**

I would be very happy for examples from all across the spectrum of realisations with references to look them up in detail.

Thank you all in advance for your suggestions.

---

*I am not sure if this question is appropriate for StackExchange as I have seen similar questions been taken down quite fast. If the community does not like open questions of this type just let me know it.

Comment: Section 3.1 in this review article lists several physical examples: https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0012164

Answer (score 1):

Let me point to one example of $\Bbb Z_2$ symmetry breaking. It is contained in my paper

S. Shlosman: Phase transitions for two-dimensional models with isotropic short-range interactions and continuous symmetry, Comm. Math. Phys. 71(1980), 207-212.

There I consider a 2D system with $O(2)$ symmetry group (which is disconnected). In agreement with the Mermin-Wagner theorem, the $SO(2)$ part of the symmetry is not broken, while the remaining $\Bbb Z_2$ symmetry is broken, at low temperatures.